# Non aggregate measure in cube

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a FactTable with Flag, this flag is to differentiate records and its of `boolean datatype`. I have to get this field in the cube. I have created non aggregatable measure for this flag, but it shows `blank/null` when cube is browsed. I do not want to create degenerate dimension.
I want the data to look like this.

```
Flag| Sales Local
1   | 35,450
0   | 22,000
```

Is there any other way to get this field into cube, or is it possible?

Comment: using a flag is often a sign you are modelling it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, but that is the only way to differentiate records, I need any other way to get this attribute into cube.

Comment: "but that is the only way to differentiate records" - No, it's not.

Comment: A flag is tied to a record in the fact table. If you break up this fact table and want to instead associate this with individual attributes, will it make any sense? I guess not. So the only way you can get the metrics is to have a junk dimension(a separate dimension with 1 and 0)

Comment: I will buy it. I created junk dimension and linked to fact. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'dimensional way' to model flags is in a 'Junk' dimension:

[Design Tip #113 Creating, Using, and Maintaining Junk Dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/)

Comment: I have created Junk Dimension and linked to fact. Exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

A possible workaround would be to add whichever measure that might be required for this column in the cube itself. E.g. `Countfoo`, `Countbar`, `SumSalesLocalfoo` and `SumSalesLocalbar`. But on the downside, you wont exactly get what you want. But you can get something like:

```
SumSalesLocalfoo| SumSalesLocalbar
35,450          | 22,000
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10550405)

Comment: It does answer the question to some extent. If you think it doesn't, request you to come up with one. And if you care to look up, i DID ask my question as a comment.